# Spring Cloud Sleuth trace ID propagation via Spring Cloud Stream Binder for AWS Kinesis

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am trying to ensure that Spring Cloud Sleuth trace IDs are sent as headers over Kinesis based on what I have read [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/1.3.x/multi/multi__customizations.html). If I'm reading the Spring Cloud Kinesis binder documentation correctly that is available [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc#kinesis-binder-properties), I would think that the configuration, producer, and consumer code below would allow the X-B3-TraceId header to be successfully sent from the producer to consumer. However, this does not currently work, as the header is not available on the consumer side. Using the AWS Kinesis Binder, how can I pass this header from producer to consumer? What is my configuration and code missing below?

Spring Boot: 2.6.7

Spring Cloud: 2021.0.1

Spring Cloud Stream Binder for AWS Kinesis: 2.2.0

**Configuration**:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kinesis:
        binder:
          headers:
            - X-B3-TraceId
```

**Producer**:

```
accountChannels
        .accountRequest()
        .send(
            MessageBuilder.withPayload(accountEvent)
                .setHeader("X-B3-TraceId", getTraceId())
                .build());
...
```

**Consumer**:

```
@StreamListener(ApplicationChannels.ACCOUNT_REQUEST)
  public void processAccountRequest(
      final Message<AccountEvent> message,
      @Header(AwsHeaders.CHECKPOINTER) final IRecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer,
      @Header("X-B3-TraceId") final String traceId) {
...
```

**Results of logging MessageHeaders in consumer:**

```
Received message header b3 and value 3e6c8447beeff928-3e6c8447beeff928-0
Received message header nativeHeaders and value {b3=[3e6c8447beeff928-3e6c8447beeff928-0]}
Received message header x-b3-traceid and value 304f6cc831322a5c
Received message header aws_shard and value shardId-000000000000
Received message header aws_checkpointer and value com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.RecordProcessorCheckpointer@338f0685
Received message header id and value 7754e5ff-e09d-886c-a425-8e0068a57a89
Received message header sourceData and value UserRecord [subSequenceNumber=0, explicitHashKey=null, aggregated=false, getSequenceNumber()=49625973706469884904499220492564923628215483380266958850, getData()=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=171 cap=171], getPartitionKey()=8162231937]
Received message header contentType and value application/vnd.accountevent.v1+avro
Received message header aws_receivedPartitionKey and value 8162231937
Received message header aws_receivedStream and value account-request
Received message header aws_receivedSequenceNumber and value 49625973706469884904499220492564923628215483380266958850
Received message header timestamp and value 1650915186028
```

Comment: So, you confirm that `AccountEvent` is deserialized properly, but there is just no that `X-B3-TraceId` header on the consumer side? May that mean that `.setHeader("X-B3-TraceId", getTraceId())` result is `null`? Kinda no value for a header, so nothing to send into Kinesis stream?..

Comment: When I use the ```@Header("X-B3-TraceId")``` annotation as noted above, the value is not resolved as a header. However, I see it in the logs when I added ```var messageHeaders = message.getHeaders();
for (Entry<String, Object> entry : messageHeaders.entrySet()) {
  log.info("Received message header {} and value {}", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}```

In either case, the b3 header that I see when I log the message in the consumer is not the same trace id I see logged in the producer.

Comment: Why do you think that this header is not overridden just before it is reaching the Kinesis producer? It would be great if  you are able to debug `EmbeddedHeaderUtils` to see what exactly header you send and what headers you receive.

Comment: I added the results of logging out the MessageHeaders in the consumer in my original post. Will EmbeddedHeaterUtils log something out different? If so, where should I place that code? In my consumer, producer, or both? And, which method should I call on it?

Comment: Please note that I tried changing the header name to all lowercase since my original post to test whether case sensitivity made a difference or not. Again, I'm trying to propagate the trace id that is logged out as the x-b3-traceid from the producer and get the consumer to use that value as its trace id.

Comment: The `EmbeddedHeaderUtils` is called by the framework. It does not log anything. That's why I suggested to debug it. Any chances you can share with us a simple project so I can test it on my side against Localstack?

Comment: Unfortunately the organization I work for does not allow us to share code on public sites, outside of posts like the one I made. Really, any simple producer/consumer example would work. In addition, you'll want to ensure Spring Cloud Sleuth is in the mix. Log out the trace id with something like ```tracer.currentSpan().context().traceIdString()``` on the producer side, send a message on the producer side using ```MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).setHeader("X-B3-TraceId", traceIdValue).build();```, and log out the ```MessageHeaders``` on the consumer side where the message is received.

Comment: OK. I will play with that. Thank you! What deps to add for Spring Cloud Sleuth? And is that `tracer` is just a bean auto-configured from there? The reason I'm asking because I'm not so good with tracing.

Comment: Just add ```org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth``` as a dependency. Also, autowire into your code ```brave.Tracer```. I also have a pom import of ```org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.6.7``` and ```org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.1``` in a parent pom we use to manage our libraries. Also, and I mentioned this above, we are using ```org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis:2.2.0```. I really wish I could post code to save you the hassle. Really sorry about that, and I truly appreciate you looking into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Spring Cloud application like this:

**application.properties**

```
logging.level.root=warn

spring.sleuth.tracer.mode=brave

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=test-stream
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=my-group
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=test-stream
spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.headers=X-B3-TraceId
```

**So72003034Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding({ Source.class, Sink.class })
public class So72003034Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So72003034Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void processAccountRequest(
            Message<String> message,
            @Header("X-B3-TraceId") final String traceId) {

        System.out.println("Consumer trace: " + traceId);
    }

}
```

**So72003034ApplicationTests**

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = "cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1")
@Testcontainers(disabledWithoutDocker = true)
@DirtiesContext
class So72003034ApplicationTests {

    @Container
    public static LocalStackContainer localStack =
            new LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack"))
                    .withServices(LocalStackContainer.Service.KINESIS);


    @Autowired
    Source source;

    @Autowired
    Tracer tracer;

    @Test
    void testTracingPropagation() throws InterruptedException {
        String traceId = this.tracer.newTrace().context().traceIdString();
        System.out.println("Producer trace: " + traceId);
        this.source.output()
                .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("tet")
                        .setHeader("X-B3-TraceId", traceId)
                        .build());

        Thread.sleep(10_000);
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class LocalStackConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public AmazonKinesisAsync amazonKinesis() {
            return AmazonKinesisAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withEndpointConfiguration(localStack.getEndpointConfiguration(LocalStackContainer.Service.KINESIS))
                    .withCredentials(localStack.getDefaultCredentialsProvider())
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public LockRegistry lockRegistry() {
            return new DefaultLockRegistry();
        }

        @Bean
        public ConcurrentMetadataStore checkpointStore() {
            return new SimpleMetadataStore();
        }

    }

}
```

I see that `X-B3-TraceId` header is propagated from producer to consumer over the Kinesis stream.

I cannot confirm with KCL enabled since its producer library doesn't work on Windows any more.

I also see in debug mode that received message container a `b3` header. Perhaps the one populated by Spring Cloud Sleuth automatically.

**UPDATE**

The working strategy is to propagate the whole `b3` header:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.headers=b3
```

The producer for me looks like this, just because there is no trace in action yet:

```
    ScopedSpan scopedSpan = this.tracer.startScopedSpan("test");
    String traceId = scopedSpan.context().traceId();
    System.out.println("Producer trace: " + traceId);
    this.source.output().send(new GenericMessage<>("test"));
    scopedSpan.end();
```

This way the `TracingChannelInterceptor` is able to take the trace from the `ThreadLocal`, start a new span and set it into a `b3` header.

On the consumer side I have:

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
public void processAccountRequest(Message<String> message,
        @Header("b3") final String trace) {

    System.out.println("Consumer b3: " + trace);
}
```

Which indeed shows the same trace as I send on the producer:

```
Producer trace: 957fd8316345f39f
Consumer b3: 957fd8316345f39f-44810ee5bf7cb0b7-0
```

Comment: Does your ```@StreamListener```'s b3 header's traceId match the one that your test logged out? In other words, is the traceId propagated correctly from producer to consumer so that, over Kinesis, both trace ids match?

Comment: Well, we don't propagate `b3` header. It is not included into supported: `spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.headers=X-B3-TraceId`. We propagate here only `X-B3-TraceId` and some standard header. So, I'm not sure why the question has shifted to `b3`...

Comment: I ask because the reason I posted in the first place was because I'm trying to get the producer's trace id propagated into the consumer's trace context so that we can search in our log aggregator and see that the producer and consumer work was done within the same tracing context. In other words, I am trying to find out if it's possible to, using Spring Cloud Stream Binder for AWS Kinesis and Spring Cloud Sleuth, get this accomplished and, if so, how. I hope that clarifies why I was wondering if the b3 on the consumer side matched the producer's X-B3-TraceId, showing the integration works.

Comment: Our logback configuration contains ```%-23.23(Trace: %X{traceId})```, and by logging on both the producer and consumer side, that's how we see that the traceId matches or not.

Comment: As I said: I'm not so good with tracing. So, tell me, please, what has to match and what would be great to propagate? BTW your `tracer.currentSpan().context().traceIdString()` is empty for me. There is just no context at the moment I send a message. That's why it would be great to have some simple project from you to play with. Otherwise it looks like we deal with fully different environment. Sorry, I don't know how to configure that logback.

Comment: The b3 header value on the consumer side should be composed of three parts. The first part, before the first dash, is the trace id. If that value on the consumer side matches the X-B3-TraceId header you propagated over Kinesis, then that would prove that the Spring Cloud Sleuth tracing context was propagated correctly over Kinesis. If not, then it likely does not work and isn't integrated into Spring Cloud Stream for AWS Kinesis.

Comment: Here's an example from my consumer-side logs where they don't match: ```{b3=[3e6c8447beeff928-3e6c8447beeff928-0]}, x-b3-traceid=304f6cc831322a5c,```. This means a new tracing context was created on the consumer side, and when we search in our log aggregator, we won't be able to tie the consumer with the producer via the trace id to see that the work done by the producer and consumer is really a single business unit of work.

Comment: OK. Thank you for explanation! Now it is more cleaner. Well, when I do this `String b3 = B3SingleFormat.writeB3SingleFormat(this.tracer.newTrace().context());` and `.setHeader("b3", b3)`, then I got something this on the producer: `Producer b3: d0f2d12ac4671de3-d0f2d12ac4671de3-0`. And something like this on the consumer: `Consumer b3: d0f2d12ac4671de3-a862e45c72cd0f3e-0`. So, according your expectations it is what it has to be. Let me check just with `x-b3-traceid` propagation!

Comment: What we can't do is propagate the entire b3 value across Kinesis from producer to consumer, as Spring Cloud Sleuth is responsible for generating this actual value. The second segment of the b3 header is the span id, and it should be different across the producer and consumer. The Spring Cloud Sleuth does a good job of explaining these different parts. It's the first part, the trace id, that ties the producer and consumer together in a log aggregator. If you log messages out with logback and send HTTP requests between two microservices and then look at their logs, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: This tracing propagation feature that I am describing is a key feature for us that appears to be missing as we do work across multiple microservices that communicate with each other using Spring Cloud Stream Binder for AWS Kinesis and log activity out. I would imagine that there are other customers that would benefit from tighter integration between Spring Cloud Sleuth and Spring Cloud Stream Binder for AWS Kinesis. The work you all do is amazing, and we benefit from it in a big way. So if this gives you an idea to take back to the teams you work with, that would be great! I appreciate it all!

Comment: We cannot propagate `X-B3-TraceId` header. It is removed by the `TracingChannelInterceptor`. And this one populated only a `b3` header. I just don't see any problems with propagating this whole `b3`. Looks like Sleuth is able to parse it properly on the consumer side and continue span, respectively.

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: OK! Let me make similar changes to my project to test this out! Thank you, @Artem Bilan! I didn't think that propagating the whole b3 header would be the answer.

Comment: As an update, after adding ```spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.headers=b3``` to propagate the entire ```b3``` header, the producer and consumer share the same trace id yet have unique span ids. Thank you, @ArtemBilan, for taking the time to assist with this. I don't recall finding this solution across any of the Spring documentation, so it might be helpful to add this to the Spring Cloud Stream Binder for AWS Kinesis docs or perhaps the Spring Cloud Sleuth docs. If I missed where this was documented, then my apologies.

Comment: Well, we may consider to have this `b3` header propagated automatically. Please, raise a respective GH issue against Spring Cloud Stream. Technically we have it documented that any custom headers have to specified for propagation over Kinesis. That's on one side. On other hand, the `b3` is Spring Cloud Sleuth header feature. So, that has to be documented over there. But I agree that for convenience it has to be at least mentioned in the Kinesis Binder docs. Thank you for configuration that feature still works in the end!