# Send Spring Cloud Sleuth trace IDs as headers over Kinesis - functional model

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm trying to get Spring Cloud Sleuth trace ids to propagate into Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis messages.

Part of my configuration in application.yml file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kinesis:
        binder:
          headers:
            - spring.cloud.function.definition
            - env
            - X-B3-TraceId
```

This is how I'm publishing the message:

```
streamBridge.send(SERVICE_STREAM, "kinesis", message);
```

This is how I'm building the message:

```
protected <T> Message<T> buildMessagefrom(T entity) {
    val clazz = entity.getClass();
    return MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(entity)
            ...some other headers
            .setHeader("env", "local")
            .setHeader("spring.cloud.function.definition", "myConsumer")
            .setHeader("X-B3-TraceId", "123")
            .build();
}
```

I wrote a test to check the presence of the headers in the message being published and this is my consumer:

```
@Bean("myConsumer")
Consumer<Message<AppointmentCreatedEvent>> myConsumer() {
    return message -> {

    };
}
```

When I debug my test and check the headers in message, all of the headers I'm setting except X-B3-TraceId are present.

I followed this thread which seems to be using the annotation model:
[Spring Cloud Sleuth trace ID propagation via Spring Cloud Stream Binder for AWS Kinesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72003034/spring-cloud-sleuth-trace-id-propagation-via-spring-cloud-stream-binder-for-aws)

I wonder if the trace ids progation is supported in the functional model?

Comment: Let's see if that is intentional in your testing to have those names different in the config and in the code: `X-B3-TraceId` against `x-b3-traceid`

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a copy-paste issue, I edited my initial post to show my actual code. Just to clarify, it does not work that way.

Comment: Could it be that Function Routing does not support these headers prooagation?

Comment: I think it really could be the case then: Kinesis does not support headers by itself and that binder just embeds them into a record body. That is done via specific `ChannelInterceptor`. I somehow feel like this channel interceptor is not involved with `StreamBridge`. Consider to use a `Supplier` instead.

Comment: Would a Channel Interceptor do the trick?

Comment: Even using a Supplier, that "X-B3-TraceId" seems to be suppressed. Give it different name and it's there.
    
@Bean
    public Supplier<Message<String>> customSupplier() {
        return () -> {
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload("some message").setHeader("X-B3-TraceId", "123").build();
        };
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would a Channel Interceptor do the trick?

It can, but I don't know how that is easy going to be for you. We need an `EmbeddedHeaderUtils.embedHeaders()` utility and `NewDestinationBindingCallback` to intercept those dynamic channels in the `StreamBrindge` and be able to modify sent messages via injected `ChannelInterceptor`.

I'm looking into a way to embedded this embedded headers logic directly into Kinesis binder and its components. Turns out it is a binder specific feature and no all core Spring Cloud Stream components support this or going at all.

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure what is going on with your environment, but here is what I have so far with the latest Spring Cloud Stream `4.0.1` and `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-3.0.0`.

My `application.properties`

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.kinesisConsumer-in-0.destination=my-event
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.kinesisConsumer-in-0.group=my-group
spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.headers=X-B3-TraceId,my-name
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class KinesisBinderObservationDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KinesisBinderObservationDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<String>> kinesisConsumer(QueueChannel testBuffer) {
        return testBuffer::send;
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueChannel testBuffer() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

}
```

And test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
class KinesisBinderObservationDemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    StreamBridge streamBridge;

    @Autowired
    QueueChannel testBuffer;

    @Test
    void tracesArePropagateOverKinesis() {
        this.streamBridge.send("my-event",
                MessageBuilder.withPayload("test data")
                        .setHeader("my-name", "Test Test")
                        .setHeader("spring.cloud.function.definition", "myConsumer")
                        .setHeader("X-B3-TraceId", "123")
                        .build());

        Message<?> receive = this.testBuffer.receive(60_000);
        assertThat(receive).isNotNull();
        assertThat(receive.getPayload()).isEqualTo("test data");
        assertThat(receive.getHeaders())
                .containsKeys("my-name", "X-B3-TraceId")
                .doesNotContainKey("spring.cloud.function.definition");
    }

}
```

So, I'm taking it back: we don't need anything extra in our configuration to propagate header over Kinesis binder using `StreamBridge`. Right, we still need that `spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.headers` configuration property, but we always have needed it anyway.

Comment: I understand. I'll try on my own and see if I can get it to work, even though it looks challenging. Thanks!

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is something funny, this intertector does inject "my-name" header but not "X-B3-TraceId", I mean, when I inspect the headers in the consumer I can see that "my-name" is present, "X-B3-TraceId" is not.

```
public class OutputChannelInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        MessageHeaderAccessor messageHeaderAccessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getMutableAccessor(message);
        messageHeaderAccessor.setHeader("my-name", "Henry");
        messageHeaderAccessor.setHeader("X-B3-TraceId", "123");
        return new GenericMessage<>(message.getPayload(), messageHeaderAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
    }

}
```